# How can I CSS code transfer jquery animate() code?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm a student form South Korea studying coding jquery mobile.
and i want to make mobile web app!
I was making some slot machine animation with starting shaking motion.
And I made it by CSS code.
But for starting this animation, I had to use 'js'.
So, I want to change (jquery animate code) from this "css"

```
window.onload = function() {
var myShakeEvent = new Shake({
    threshold: 15
});
myShakeEvent.start();
window.addEventListener('shake', shakeEventDidOccur, false);
function shakeEventDidOccur () {
    $('#lot').animate({

    ~~~here I want to input the animation.~~

    }, 5000, function() {

    });
}
```

And this is css animation.

```
 <div data-role="main" class="lot">
 <div id="a"></div>
 <div id="b"></div>
 <div id="c"></div>
 </div>


<style>
*{ padding: 38px;
margin:1px;
overflow: hidden;
 }                               
 .lot{
max-height: 880px;
max-width: 270px;

 }
 #a { 
background-size:contain;
background-image: url(b1.jpg);
background-position: top;
background-repeat:repeat-x;    
animation: animatedBackground 5s ease;
animation-iteration-count: 1;
animation-direction: alternate;
}   
 #b { 
background-size:contain;
background-image: url(b2.jpg);
background-position: top;
background-repeat:repeat-x;    
animation: animatedBackground2 5s ease;
animation-iteration-count: 1;
animation-direction: alternate;
}   
 #c { 
background-size:contain;
background-image: url(b3.jpg);
background-position: top;
background-repeat:repeat-x;    
animation: animatedBackground3 5s ease;
animation-iteration-count: 1;
animation-direction: alternate;
}   
 @keyframes animatedBackground {
from { background-position: 0 0; }
50% { background-position: 5000px 0; }
to { background-position: 0 0; }
}
 @keyframes animatedBackground2 {
from { background-position: 0 0; }
50% { background-position: -5000% 0; }
to { background-position: 0 0; }
}
 @keyframes animatedBackground3 {
from { background-position: 0 0; }
50% { background-position: 4000% 0; }
to { background-position: 0 0; }
}
</style>
```

Comment: CSS is preferred over JS animation as it's hardware accelerated. That said, you can tidy your CSS up a lot by not repeating the shared properties on all elements

Comment: You could just us js/jq to toggle a class. All the animation part would still be handled by CSS. `but for starting this animation, i had to use 'js'` Depending HTML markup and expected behaviour, a CSS only solution could be used most of the time. Now if you want more specific help, you have to provide minimalistic sample in question itself

Comment: Can you edit the question and add animate function as well. Right now, it is not clear what you are trying to do?